# Trying to invoke bean application via applescript, on creating a new document, getting an error

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript

The application Bean is getting Invoked, but failing to reate a new document
Following is the error "Bean got an error: Can’t make class document." number -2710 from document to class

I'm a newbie in this, please help

Comment: You'll have to show us your code if you want a decent answer.

Comment: tell application "Bean"
Make new document
End tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Bean have AppleScript support? You can check here: AppleScript Editor --> File --> Open Dictionary

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.What could be the other way of achieving this?

Comment: You can use System Events to simulate clicks and keystrokes.